# How to transpose a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in csv that looks like this:
[image]

I want to tranpose it to look like this, where the columns are nmow rows of a new column called ACCOUNTLABEL, and the values are in a corresponding column called VALUE:
[image]

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just noticed that your question has nothing to do with [transposing](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javaexercise.com%2Fimg%2Fpython%2Fdataframe-transpose-demo.png&f=1&nofb=1) a `DataFrame`.

Use [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) for this. It uses the linked method.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, OP does not want to transpose

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at `pandas.melt` function : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

I wouldn't call that a 'transposition' but 'un-pivoting' a table.